# Vba for loop to repeat code output for cell rage

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

How can I make a for loop to repeat this code between N5 to N11

```
Dim rw As Long
    
    If Range("K6") = True Then 'Holiday Check
           
        rw = [RandBetween(6,25)]
        Range("N5") = Cells(rw, 21)
               
    ElseIf Range("I6") = True Then 'Weekend Check
    
       
        rw = [RandBetween(5,28)]
        Range("N5") = Cells(rw, 20)
        
    Else 'Else Weekday
        
        rw = [RandBetween(5,65)]
        Range("N5") = Cells(rw, 19)
   
 
               
    End If
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the documentation for [For...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) and [For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement)loops which explains how the syntax works for each of the loops.

To achieve your goal, you can consider the following:

- Use a variable for either your cell reference or row number
- Increment that variable with each step of your loop
- Replace the hard coded range reference to reference either the cell or row number variable.

I will demonstrate the `For Each...Next` method.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub UsingAForLoop()

Dim TargetCell As Range

For Each TargetCell In Range("N5:N11")

    If Range("K6") = True Then 'Holiday Check
        rw = [RandBetween(6,25)]
        TargetCell = Cells(rw, 21)    
    ElseIf Range("I6") = True Then 'Weekend Check 
        rw = [RandBetween(5,28)]
        TargetCell = Cells(rw, 20)
    Else 'Else Weekday  
        rw = [RandBetween(5,65)]
        TargetCell = Cells(rw, 19)
    End If

Next TargetCell

End Sub
```

This example loops through each cell in the range `Range("N5:N11")` and follows your if logic each time. When the condition is met, the `TargetCell` for that iteration will be populated with the data per your `Cells()` reference.

If you need to change the other references as part of your `IF...Then` statements you can follow the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rw As Long

For I = 5 To 11

    If Range("K6") = True Then 'Holiday Check
           
        rw = [RandBetween(6,25)]
        Range("N" & I) = Cells(rw, 21)
               
    ElseIf Range("I6") = True Then 'Weekend Check
    
       
        rw = [RandBetween(5,28)]
        Range("N" & I) = Cells(rw, 20)
        
    Else 'Else Weekday
        
        rw = [RandBetween(5,65)]
        Range("N" & I) = Cells(rw, 19)
                  
    End If

Next I
```